# iOS: Download script and execute it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

We have an app that basically parsers some web pages. The thing is the structure of the web page changes sometimes so we need to issue an update (wait for apple's approval of course). We would like to have the ability to have some kind of a "script logic" on our server that can be sent to the app whenever needed. JavaScript code is possible, but I don't want to have a UIWebView just for parsing some strings. Is there some kind of alternative?

Thanks

Comment: If your app just executes web pages, it likely will be rejected.

Comment: Related : this question http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112436/apple-ios-review-and-interpreted-code-download-execution
And this post http://info.meteor.com/blog/Apple-hot-code-push-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are mainly looking for a way to parse strings, one possibility is using regular expressions to do the job and thus provide the definition for those regex in a text or xml file that you can download. This is not a full scripted solution, like one where you download the code and execute it, but it should work equally well. I suppose this should be also completely ok with Apple terms.

There are several frameworks for iOS that offer regex support: [RegExKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/), [AGRegEx](http://colloquy.info/project/browser/trunk/Frameworks/AGRegex), and in iOS 4 you have also [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I think this is the best solution for simple parsing of strings.

Answer (score 5):

No. Running executables or scripts which are not an embedded component of your application is explicitly forbidden by the developer program license agreement:

> **3.3.2.** An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework.

Comment: Correct, no downloading executable or interpreted code. That said, downloading a configuration file that describes how a web page is laid out -- e.g. divs with a class of "mainttl" should be inserted into the local data store in the "Main Title" property of an object -- wouldn't necessarily be considered interpreted code. If you can keep the logic in the shipping app (and yes, this is certainly wide open for gray areas) and out of the download you won't be violating that section.

Comment: Wouldn't downloading an AES encrypted JS payload be the same as using a dumbed down description format?

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree with this. Existing Apps like WeChat ( https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wechat/id414478124?mt=8 ) and Puzzle & Dragons download plugins and add new features to it within the App . How can they achieve it ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: By having all the code for those features resident in the main application, and only activating it when the appropriate IAP is purchased.

Comment: In the app mentioned above, IAP is not involved. They download >10MB data from their server & new features popped up... well, I guess it is the graphics then. can't prove though

Answer (score 0):

You could embed a scripting language like lua. See [here](http://maniacdev.com/2010/10/tutorial-how-to-embed-lua-in-ios-apps/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937136/lua-on-iphone). I don't know too much about it, but it's used in lots of applications for scripting, just like your needs.

I'm not 100% how to integrate it or if scripts can be hot loaded, but it will probably work.

Note:

I'm not sure if Apple would let you download and run arbitrary scripts, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Lua scripts are definitely interpreted locally in a variety of iOS games; however, the scripts must already exist in the app when installed, they can't subsequently be downloaded and interpreted.

Comment: @tjameson: Thanks, I have looked at lua a bit and it's very different from the C syntax... So is there a more "c like" option ?

Comment: Good point. I read that somewhere else, and it's 100% consistent with Apple's terms. Still, worth a shot.

Comment: @Alex1987- No, JavaScript is the closest you'll get. I'd try to avoid breaking Apple's terms as much as possible. Make your code as robust as possible, and if you need  extra features, do it on the server-side where running arbitrary code is allowed (Apple can't get their dirty little fingers in there).

Comment: @tjameson: Yeah the problem with JS is that I need to keep a UIWebView for that which is very expensive. I wonder if there is a way to execute simple JS code without having a UIWebView

Comment: You're dealing with things that Apple does not like. You will likely have you app rejected from the app store. If you want flexibility, do that server-side and then give the results to your app. As for running JS code, there is a port of nodejs for iPhone, but it's likely even heavier than a UIWebview.