# Calling Lua scripts from iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, lua

How would one call a Lua script from a block of Objective-C in an iOS app?  Also, would an app that calls Lua scripts be accepted by Apple's review process?

Comment: I'm the only one that wants to run LUA on IOS?

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem with running Lua code on iOS. The only thing that is banned by Apple is executing scripts that were downloaded from the network. All your executable code should be either bundled along with your app or user-created. For example, there's a great Lua IDE for the iPad called [Codea](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/).

For the technical side of your question please see [Lua on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937136/lua-on-iphone)